# Dose pd.read_csv skiprows parameter support skip empty lines?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file like below:

```
                                                               SUMMARY OF SURFACE ENERGY BALANCE


              INCOMING                NET SOLAR RADIATION BY MATERIAL                               NET LONG-WAVE RADIATION BY MATERIAL
               SOLAR   REFLECTED ------------------------------------------  INCOMING OUTGOING   -----------------------------------------
 DAY HR  YR   ON SLOPE   SOLAR   CANOPY     SNOW   RESIDUE    SOIL    TOTAL  LONGWAVE LONGWAVE   CANOPY    SNOW   RESIDUE    SOIL    TOTAL  SENSIBLE  LATENT    SOIL
                 W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2     W/M2




 338 24   86     30.8      5.6     19.4      0.0      5.4      0.5     25.3    290.6    317.5    -16.4      0.0     -6.3     -4.1    -26.9     -4.7     -0.8     -6.8
 339 24   86     11.6      5.6      4.8      1.2      0.0      0.0      6.0    301.5    311.4     -5.2     -3.5     -0.4     -0.7     -9.9      1.3     -0.1     -7.1

...
```

The file's 1st, 3rd, 4th, 10th, 11th, and 12th line are empty.

Line 7 is the header.

The line after line 13 is data.

I want to read it into a dataframe and do some analysis.

To achieve this I must:

- set the 7th line as the header
- skip the 8th line (which is not data line)

If I use this code can get the correct result:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=3, skiprows=[7])
print(df.head())
```

Which will print like this:

```
   DAY HR  YR   ON SLOPE   SOLAR   CANOPY     SNOW   RESIDUE    SOIL    TOTAL  LONGWAVE LONGWAVE   CANOPY    SNOW   RESIDUE    SOIL    TOTAL  SENSIBLE  LATENT    SOIL
0   338 24   86     30.8      5.6     19.4      0...                                                                                                                  
1   339 24   86     11.6      5.6      4.8      1...                                                                                                                  
2   340 24   86     22.2     18.5      0.0      3...                                                                                                                  
3   341 24   86     22.8     18.7      0.0      4...                                                                                                                  
4   342 24   86     48.4     37.0      4.4      7...
```

However, when I called the read_csv function, set the header parameter to 3, and set the skiprows parameter to 7 I get this result (even though I need skiprow to just apply after the header row).

The header has ignored the empty lines before header, but the skiprows can't ignore empty lines before which will be skipped.

*Conclusion*

So I want to know can skiprows parameter ignore the empty lines?

If possible, I just need know the number of skiprows after header row number, and ignoring the need to count it from top.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and it seems like not, the reason is because `header` ignores lines when the parameter `skip_blank_lines` is set to `True` (by default), but `skiprows` does not take into account that parameter.

You could, however, just read without the `skiprows` parameter and drop the `na` values.

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=3, skip_blank_lines=True).dropna()
```

But to be honest this might not be a good idea, because dtypes will be set to `objects` for the affected columns with `na` values.

Comment: I'd test this,But this result contains the line which I want to ignore.

Comment: how? if the data is not complete then some of the columns will be nan values which are drop, but yeah at this stage there is no way to change the beahvior of `skiprow`

Comment: The 8th line. If want to drop this line must set the skiprows parameter.

Comment: The line does not have values for every column so it will include `nan` values at the end, and the `read_csv` is dropping nan values, which will drop the entire row, but again, this is just a raw solution if you don't want to use `skiprows`.